# Converting SQL query with a join on a sub query, to HQL

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

I did not manage to convert this kind of query in *HQL* :

```
SELECT table.*
FROM Table table, (SELECT kind, max(date) as maxdate FROM Table GROUP BY kind) subrequest
WHERE table.kind = subrequest.kind AND date = subrequest.maxdate
```

Table is a big table and contains many attributes, I want to select the last entries of each kind.
By doing the sub query in FROM part, I save a lot of time. Any idea ?

Original query was :

```
SELECT table.*
FROM Table table
WHERE table.date = (SELECT max(date) FROM Table WHERE kind = table.kind)
```

It's easy to convert in *HQL* but slower.